# TreeView - How to set Parent node from data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, parent, treelist

I filled treelist from database using dataset.

```
tree.ItemsSource = new _e_shopping24CategoriesParentTableAdapters.CategoriesTableAdapter().GetData();
```

There are 3 tables in dataset:

1. IDCategory
2. Name
3. Parent

I set **DisplayMemberPath** to **Name**. But i can't find any parameter that set Parent node to tree.

So my TreeView looks like this:

- Drinks
- Pepsi
- CocaCola
- Cars
- Subaru
- Mercedes

but I want:

1. Drinks

   1. Pepsi
   2. Coca cola
2. Cars

   1. Subaru
   2. Mercedes

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Thaks a lot.

Comment: can you explain the structure of your database tables, this will be important to answer, I don't think there is a way to have it automatically read the tree as you would like.  However if you post the database structure I can help you out populating the tree manually

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought there is a way how to fill it automatically. I know how to fill it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to create and populate data structure where each category contains a list of items:

```
public class Category
{
    private readonly IList<Item> _items;

    public Category()
    {
        _items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> Items { get { return _items; } }
}

public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You will then need to create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for your `TreeView`.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#DataTemplating_HeirarchicalDataTemplate) for a great example of how to create one.